# What does the order of nested quantifiers in predicate logic express?

Tags: logic, semantics, quantification

I was looking at [this](https://people.cs.pitt.edu/~milos/courses/cs441/lectures/Class4.pdf) short and helpful slideshow

[image]

But it's early: in general, what does the ordering of quantifiers translate to?

Comment: is it right to say that it the second quantified variable is a predicate of the former ?

Comment: **Lxy** is a *binary* predicate, i.e. a *relation* : "x Loves y", "x is son of y". Quantifying a variable : **∃yLxy** we have a *unary* predicate (a "property"). With the "Love" example, we have "there is (someone) loved by x". Thus, in a sense YES, this depends on **x**.

Comment: order determines scope of quantification.

Comment: @mobileink that's true but seems to me to just restate the fact in the slideshow that the order of quantification *matters* to quantification. i'm not sure. conifold's answer was good, and interesting, but i'm still unsure how to phrase it in everyday terms. is **the latter variable always a predicate of the former**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to interpret the order of nested quantifiers is as expressing dependence relations among choices of objects selected to satisfy the quantified formula. [Friedman in Kant's Theory of Geometry](http://izt.ciens.ucv.ve/ecologia/Archivos/Filosofia-II/Friedman,%20Michael%20-%20Kant's%20theory%20of%20geometry.pdf) explains how the inability to express such dependencies in syllogistic (you need three nested quantifiers to define limits, for example) forced early calculus and analysis to rely on intuitive ideas about motion rather than formal constructions. And in turn it led Kant to his synthetic a priori theory of mathematical reasoning.

For example ∀x∃yL(x,y) means that there exists a y for every x, i.e. we must select y dependently on x, or y=f(x). The dequantified formula is L(x,f(x)) and x can be chosen freely, the function f will then ensure that the predicate is satisfied. In this example f is a "lovefinder" function, for every x it finds y who x loves. But ∃y∀xL(x,y) is different, means that there is a universal y for all x, a constant y=c, a universally beloved, like Santa. So the formula reduces to L(x,c), a different dependence pattern.

The outlined procedure is called Skolemization, and any quantified formula can be converted into a dequantified form by using [Skolem functions and constants](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Skolem_function), which reveal the dependencies explicitly. Universally quantified variables are freely chosen, and existentially quantified ones must be chosen depending on all universally quantified ones, whose ∀ precede their ∃. For example, ∀x∃y∀z∃tL(x,y,z,t) means that x and z are freely chosen, choice of y again depends only on x, so y=f(x), but choice of t depends on both x and z, so t=g(x,z). The Skolemized formula is L(x,f(x),z,g(x,z)). Moving the quantifiers around and Skolemizing you'll see how satisfaction dependencies change. This is what parsing of the trees in Keelan's answer equivalently describes.

[Skolemization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_normal_form#Uses_of_Skolemization) can be used to build models of formal theories out of their own symbols, at it were. This is how Skolem originally discovered that all finite first order theories have countable models, after all we can only generated a countable number of Skolemized symbols. It is also used for automated theorem proving, by building a Skolem model where the formula is satisfied.

Comment: Friedman says, "For us, the conjunction of 'X is a triangle' with these axioms does of course imply 'X's angles sum to 180°' by logic alone; and no spatio-temporal activity of construction is necessary." He recognizes the need for the axioms, dismissing the forms of intuition. However, he fails to see that that is precisely Kant's point: The need of the axioms *is* the need for the forms of intuition, because there is no basis for the former without the latter.

Comment: @PédeLeão I think on Kant's view synthetic construction is needed even *with* the axioms, and can do without them altogether, they are more of practical shortcuts. And he was right, even if we expand the Euclid's list but keep the syllogistic, his theory reflects the practice of his time. Friedman shows, convincingly I think, how Newton and Kant used kinematic intuitions to make up for the lack of quantifier dependence. But axioms do not *need* to come from intuition, Newton's laws didn't, and justification can be by successful practice as a whole, or large chunks of it, as with ZFC axioms.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When you say that the axioms don't need to come from intuition, I'm guessing that you mean that they're somewhat arbitrary, exchangeable for some other type of geometry. That's seems to be the heart of the issue, and I'm still not convinced that it's true. I believe that both Poincaré and Friedman believe(d) that such a geometry, from some vantage point, would be perceptually distinguishable (as curvature or discontinuous density) if it were possible to achieve such a point. However, I believe that's probably a mistake.

Comment: really sorry for my stupidity, but is the 1st quantiied variable what the predicate is predicated of, which variable the predicate **belongs to**? so, suppose there is a predicate Parent(x,y) denoting “x is a parent of y”... ∀x∀yParent(x,y) means that the predicate belongs to the parent, and ∀y∀xParent(x,y) means that *the exact same* predicate belongs to the child

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN Multi-place predicates express relations, so you could say they are "predicated of" or "belong to" ordered pairs, triples.., but not individual variables. And a fully quantified formula is not "predicated of" anything because it has no free variables to predicate.  But quantifiers can be used to reduce the number of places, and in this case they can create two different one-place predicates:∀xParent(x,y), being everybody's child, and ∀yParent(x,y) being everybody's parent, which belong to the child and the parent respectively.

Comment: @PédeLeão I wasn't taking geometry specifically, but Poincare wrote in Science and Hypothesis that geometrical axioms are "*neither synthetic a priori intuitions nor experimental facts. They are conventions*", and that only the pair geometry+physics is empirically testable with each part chosen based on "convenience". Friedman in Dynamics of Reason accepts Quine's point that only whole theories are testable, not individual postulates, and Kuhn's, that design of theories is culturally influenced. His holism is more structured and conservative than theirs, but it is holism nonetheless.

Comment: @Conifold. I understand that that was what they were talking about, but it wasn't what Kant was talking about. In Friedman's article, his criticisms of Kant seemed rather misdirected. I don't doubt the abilities of Friedman and Poincaré in math and logic, but I do doubt they understood the nature of the question concerning the forms intuition. And it's not that I have any particular interest in defending Kant; it's just that I haven't yet found an argument that properly frames the question such that it would lead me to believe Kant was wrong.

Comment: @PédeLeão Maybe we are talking about different things but on my reading Friedman does not criticize Kant, he simply describes the limitations of mathematical language he had to work with. Do you mean that Kant was right in the sense of ["mental a priori"](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/17940/was-kant-right-about-space-and-time-and-wrong-about-knowledge)?

Answer (score 4):

You can see the difference when you make a parse tree for these expressions:

```
    ∀                 ∃
   / \               / \
  x   ∃             y   ∀
     / \               / \
    y   L             x   L
       / \               / \
      x   y             x   y

 ∀x∃y L(x,y)       ∃y∀x L(x,y)
```

<sub>Note: making a parse tree is similar to placing implicit parentheses: ∀x(∃y(L(x,y))) and ∃y(∀x(L(x,y))).</sub>

The first means:

- For all x, it holds that:

  - There exists some y, such that:

    - x loves y.

Or "everybody loves someone".

The second means:

- There exists a y, such that:

  - For all x:

    - x loves y.

Or "there is someone who loves everybody".

Comment: If this is not what you're looking for, please clarify your question. You ask "what does the order translate to", but the translations of the example sentences is given on the slide.

Comment: hey, thanks. i was asking what the order of quantiied variables *always* means, not just how to make sense of those two symbolic strings. the parse tree helped a little. i'm not sure if it answers my question clearly enough or not

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN what do you mean with "always means"? The order itself does not have a meaning, the predicates do. The order only holds meaning insofar it influences which expression is subordinate (i.e. how far it is down the parse tree).

Comment: "how far it is down the parse tree" exactly what i said. is there any way to couch that in terms that aren't as technical as "parse tree" ?

Comment: @MATHEMETICIAN when expression a is further down than b, it means that a is a subexpression of b. I don't know how to say it in an even less technical way, sorry.